# Trying to transfer a JSON body from httpServletRequest to httpPost

Tags: json, servlets, request, http-post, soapui

Trying to transfer a JSON body from httpServletRequest to httpPost

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
    CloseableHttpResponse proxyResponse = null;
    PrintWriter printWriterOut = servletResponse.getWriter();
    requestedPath = servletRequest.getRequestURI();
    String stringRequestedQuery = servletRequest.getQueryString();

    URI uri = buildUri(requestedPath, stringRequestedQuery);
    LOGGER.info("Obtained request method: " + servletRequest.getMethod());

    if (servletRequest.getMethod() == HttpMethod.POST) {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpPost = (HttpPost)addHeadersToHttpRequest(httpPost, servletRequest);
        proxyResponse = proxyClient.execute(httpPost);
    }
```

As you can see above, a method addHeadersToHttpRequest passes headers from a servletRequest to the httpPost object. The body, however, is not transferred. I created a JSON body on soapUI for testing.

Comment: Why did you override the `service` method?  That's generally frowned upon.

Comment: I'm creating a proxy within to relay the information unto a different target